# What does the parenthesis do in the vim custom key bindings?

Tags: linux, bash, vim, neovim

I found the following key bindings online, and I'm trying to understand how they work. What is the function of the parenthesis here?

```
" Better nav for omnicomplete
inoremap <expr> <c-j> ("\<C-n>")
inoremap <expr> <c-k> ("\<C-p>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parethesis are irrelevant, and the former mapping is just giving <kbd>Ctrl+j</kbd> the same use of <kbd>Ctrl+n</kbd> when in insert mode. Similarly happens for the latter mapping.

Therefore, what <kbd>Ctrl+j</kbd> does after that mapping depends on what <kbd>Ctrl+n</kbd> does. For instance, if you run Vim without any customization, i.e. with `vim -u NONE`, those key combos will do what is explained in `:help i_CTRL-N` and `:help i_CTRL-P`. (The leading `i_` in the help pages refers to the `i`nsert mode.)

Similarly you can see what the other two combos do in `:help i_CTRL-J` and `:help i_CTRL-K`. You'll see they do totally unrelated stuff. Probably, the user which you took those mappings from, just prefers <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to navigate, rather than <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>.